# Delete all rows from a SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to delete all rows from a SQL Server 2005 database.

Can anyone to define a procedure to delete all rows from database easily?

Comment: Uh? Drop and recreate database?

Comment: actually my database exist in server, i want only delete data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all rows from database by using single query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831753/delete-all-rows-from-database-by-using-single-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, this will work:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
```

thankyou for all.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
    --Disable Constraints & Triggers
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'
    --Perform delete operation on all table for cleanup
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DELETE ?'
    --Enable Constraints & Triggers again
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL'
    --Reset Identity on tables with identity column
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''?''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1
    BEGIN DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'',RESEED,0) END'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://vadivel.blogspot.se/2006/07/easiest-fastest-way-to-delete-all.html