# Delete all rows from database by using single query?

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete all rows from all tables in a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899846/how-to-delete-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

I want to delete all rows from a SQL Server 2005 database.

Can anyone to define a procedure to delete all rows from database by using single query?

Comment: do you mean all rows from all tables?

Comment: 1. Select all table names from your database, 2. Dynamically generate sql statements for deleting all rows, 3. Execute.

Comment: yes, i want all records from all tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, this will work:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
```

thanks @MAT

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried : delete * FROM database.* ?

Comment: That is not valid syntax in SQL Server..